# how to set selection current line to end of file in sublime plugin

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

i want to loop through current line to end of file
set to selection

> Blockquote
>   for region in view.sel():
>   Blockquote

Answer (score 1):

there is sublime.Region class Creates a Region with initial values a and b.
api reference - https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime.Region

and here is 50 examples how to use sublime.Region()
https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/52602/sublime.Region